# filtering only n elements in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Well this is a simple question i want to filter two elements sorted reverse by date.

The model is:

```
Class ModelName(models.Model):
    usr = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

The way i do it is:

```
ModelName.object.filter(param=param).order_by('-created')[:2]
```

As per my understanding what i think happens behind the scene is:

1. All the objects from ModelName are filtered
2. they are sorted
3. only two of them are selected.

Maybe i am wrong, if not then how can i filter only last two elements based on the date.

Comment: What are you trying to get that you're not currently getting?

Comment: I jsut wanted to know if there was any further optimization to the query i wrote on the database level.

Comment: I think its the normal way for RDBMS to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - All the objects from ModelName are filtered
> - they are sorted
> - only two of them are selected.

Yes, but that's done by the database, not by python. See [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). So, that actually works pretty well since all this python:

```
qs = ModelName.object.filter(param=param).order_by('-created')[:2]
```

Will be converted to SQL when qs records are accessed (ie. for model in qs ...)

Comment: just to nitpick - [slicing causes the QuerySet to be evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) so in this case so the DB will be hit immediately (but only once)

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony no, iterating on the qs evaluates it. slicing w/o step just sets low and high end of query. `Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the "step" parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list.`

Comment: Yea, just read through that again - I thought that "step" syntax referred to `[a:b]`!